# How can I keep the value of this.valueofDuration?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've declared in the data section a variable : valueofDuration and this variable gets the hh:mm:ss of an uploaded video.
[My problem occurs here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qAcC.png)
I've declared in HTML template section

```html
    <video
     preload="metadata"
      class="video mb-0 ml-0"
      id="id"
      controls="controls"
      loop
       muted
    ></video>
<v-col class="mt-4 d-flex justify-center" cols="6">
    <input
 type="file"
  id="video_selector"
  @click="llamar"
      accept=".mkv,video/*"
      />
       </v-col>
```

```js
 var au = document.getElementById("id");
          au.onloadedmetadata = function () {
            var sec_num = parseInt(au.duration, 10); // don't forget the second param
            var hours = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
            var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - hours * 3600) / 60);
            var seconds = sec_num - hours * 3600 - minutes * 60;
            if (hours < 10) {
              hours = "0" + hours;
            }
            if (minutes < 10) {
              minutes = "0" + minutes;
            }
            if (seconds < 10) {
              seconds = "0" + seconds;
            }
            // return hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
            var inputValue = document.getElementById("video_selector");
            var fileInput = inputValue;
            var fileUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(fileInput.files[0]);
            filename = fileInput.files[0].name;
            selected_file = fileInput.files[0];
            console.log(selected_file);
            console.log(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
            this.valueofDuration = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
            // let classValue = document.getElementsByClassName("video");
            // classValue.src = fileUrl
                        console.log(this.valueofDuration);

          };

          $(() => {
            console.log("Loaded DOM.");
```

[Look the image, please.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLPX3.png)That's the code and I'd like to know why it's no renderized in html because I'm getting the value of this valueofduration in line 674 and also I tested getting the value in a console (this valueofDuration)inside the function. Also I realize I can't print by console in line 678 the value of thisvalueofduration. If I print by console after line 674 inside the function, It works. any Idea please?

I realize that I loss the value after the function  au.onloadedmetadata = function ()   . Also, Why should I loss the value of this.valueduration when I get the value of hour+minute+seconds ? , thanks

Comment: You're using function expression which has its own scope and your `this` is not accessible in that function. That's why when you set `this.valueofDuration`, you actually set it in the function expression scope. If you'll try to console log it right after you set it, inside the function, you will actually see that it is set. But again, it is set in the function expression scope.

Comment: I will check that , thanks for your idea.